# Summing a column in a .csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to sum a column in a csv file using python. Here's a sample of the csv data;

```
Date,Profit/Losses
Jan-2010,867884
Feb-2010,984655
Mar-2010,322013
Apr-2010,-69417
May-2010,310503
Jun-2010,522857
Jul-2010,1033096
Aug-2010,604885
Sep-2010,-216386
```

I want to sum the Profit/Losses column.
I am using the following code but it's returning a 0. Where could I be going wrong?

```
import os
import csv

# Path to collect data from the csv file in the Resources folder
pybank_csv = os.path.join("resources", "budget_data.csv")

with open(pybank_csv, 'r') as csvfile:       
   csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
   next(csvfile, None)    
   t = sum(float(row[1]) for row in csvreader)

   #print the results
   print(f"Total: {t}")
```

Comment: The code seems to be perfectly fine. Please check that you are opening the right file and that Profit/Losses column doesn't sum up to 0 in reality (for example by leaving just a few first rows in it)

Comment: @fdermishin thanks for that. I am opening the correct file and the total of the column in the CSV file is not 0.

Comment: I ran the code on the sample you provided and got output `Total: 4360090.0`

Comment: I've added this code ' row_count = sum(1 for row in csvreader)' and it returns '9' so I know it's reading the correct file but I'm still getting a 0

Comment: Note that if you can use `csvreader` only one time. If you try to loop through it the second time, there will be no elements left in it.

Comment: ooh yes that could be where I am going wrong. I was reading the rows counts and then trying to sum using the 'code' csvreader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use pandas library.

Use `pip install pandas` to install pandas on your machine

and then

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_filename.csv')
sumcol = df['Profit/Losses'].sum()
print(sumcol)
```

The sum is in sumcol object now. For future reference, If your task is to work with the data provided in csv file, pandas is a blessing. This library provides you with thousands of different types of operations you could perform on your data. Refer [Pandas Website](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html#user-guide) for more info.

If you want to make use of csv package only then you can read the csv as a dict and then sum the Profit/Loss entry of dict for each row

```
total = 0
with open('your_filename.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in data:
        total = total + int(row['Profit/Losses'])
print(total)
```

Or If you want to use reader instead of dict reader, you need to ignore first row. Something like this

```
total = 0
with open('your_filename.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in data:
        if not str(row[1]).startswith('P'):
            total = total + int(row[1])
 print(total)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This is for a class assignment and the instructor doesn't want us to use pandas just yet. That's for next week. Just wondering why the code is returning a 0

Comment: I tested my code and sumcol prints 4360090 as it should. Also I will edit my answer to accommodate for 'csv library only' code

Comment: Thanks for the help. It now works. I'm new to python and also stackoverflow so I really appreciate your help.